# Error on NEVPNManager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, vpn, nevpnmanager

My target platform is OS X 10.10 / Xcode 7.2
I'm trying to  save the preference for NEVPNManager and I got an error in the domain=NEConfigurationErrorDomain:

```
Error Domain = NEConfigurationErrorDomain Code = 10 "permission denied" UserInfo = 0x610000073280 {NSLocalizedDescription = permission denied}
```

The sample code below:

```
let manager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
manager.loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
    if((error) != nil) {
        print("VPN load preferences error")
        print(error!)
        exit(0)
    }
    if manager.`protocol`  == nil {
        let proto = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
        proto.serverAddress = "host.net"
        proto.username = "username"
        Keychain.save("vpnpassword", data: "password".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        proto.passwordReference = Keychain.load("vpnpassword") // I got the same error without passwordReference too
        proto.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.None
        manager.`protocol` = proto
        manager.enabled = true
        manager.localizedDescription = "VPN"
        manager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler({ (error) -> Void in
            if((error) != nil) {
                print("VPN Save to Preferences error")
                print(error!)
                exit(0)
            }
            else {
                do {
                    try manager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                    print("Started error")
                } catch {
                    print("Unexpected error")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Also I found next log entries:

```
Jan 10 14:24:51 y.local nehelper[196]: app has the com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api entitlement but not the application-identifier entitlement
Jan 10 14:24:51 y.local nehelper[196]: app Failed to obtain authorization right for 3: no authorization provided
Jan 10 14:24:51 y.local app[33627]: __55-[NEVPNManager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke142: failed to save the new configuration: Error Domain=NEConfigurationErrorDomain Code=10 "permission denied" UserInfo=0x608000660240 {NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}
```

I have next entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
    <string>T76ZSM474A.app</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api</key>
    <array>
        <string>allow-vpn</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>T76ZSM474A</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>T76ZSM474A.</string>
    </array>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>T76ZSM474A.group</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And next xcent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
  <string>T76ZSM474A.vpn</string>
  <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
  <string>development</string>
  <key>com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api</key>
  <array>
  <string>allow-vpn</string>
  </array>
  <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
  <string>T76ZSM474A</string>
  <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
  <array>
  <string>T76ZSM474A.</string>
  </array>
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
  <string>T76ZSM474A.group</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

embedded.provisionprofile has allow-vpn and correct team id (T76ZSM474A)

Builded app has next codesign output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
    <string>T76ZSM474A.app</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api</key>
    <array>
        <string>allow-vpn</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>T76ZSM474A</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>T76ZSM474A.</string>
    </array>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>T76ZSM474A.group</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried to decompile Network.framework, but it isn't easy.
I checked this problem on OS X 10.11 and I didn't found problem, my app works correctly.
I copied builded app from OS X 10.11 to OS X 10.10 and I got previous error.
I think that documentation has an error and NEVPNManager not supported in OS X 10.10 or NEVPNManager on OS X 10.10 has a bug.

What did I wrong?

Comment: I suggest to look at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22943 - judging from the log you've got, it might be the issue. Another suggestion is to try run the app as `root` - you might get rid of issue and this means you'd specify you need `root` somewhere. Third suggestion is to check SDK you link against - 10.10 or 10.11 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm already tried suggestion from your link and I tried to run as root.

Comment: I tried to link to sdk 10.10, because I wish to run app on OS X 10.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had long meet with Apple Support.
They told that — NEVPNManager is not fully available on 10.10. 
You should upgrade to OS X El Capitan or use Strongswan Frontend for OS X (https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/MacOSX).